# find a regular express in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a regular expression that matches a pattern like `total (10/32)` in a sentence.

ex) `total (number/number)` type

For example `file.csv` contains:

```
aaaaaaaaa bbbbb cccccccccc ... total (10/32) ... dddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeee.'
```

how to print lines using regur expression in python?

```
import re 

str= df.category

items = re.findall('(total|Total)*\(\d\/\d\)', str) 
items


output []
```

Comment: How about `re.findall('[tT]otal \(\d+/\d+\)', your_string)`?

Comment: All aboard the regular express: Add `flags=re.I`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
[tT]otal\s*\([0-9]+/[0-9]+\)
```

**Demo**: https://regex101.com/r/Yk00r7/1/

**Code sample**:

```
import re

inStr = 'aaaaaaaaa bbbbb cccccccccc ... total (10/32) ... dddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeee.'
print(re.findall(r'[tT]otal\s*\([0-9]+/[0-9]+\)',inStr))
```

**Output:**

```
['total (10/32)']
```

**Notes:**

- Do always define your regex pattern as a raw string `r'...'` in order to keep the backslashes as literal characters.
- `[tT]otal\s*\([0-9]+/[0-9]+\)` will match strings that start by `t` or `T` (`[tT]`) followed by `otal`, followed by 0 to N whitespace char (`\s*`), then one `(`, 1 to N numbers `([0-9]+)`, a slash,  1 to N numbers `([0-9]+)` and a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. ^^
It was very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`(?i)`** to turn on case-insensitive mode inline in the regex pattern:

```
import re

# example text
x = 'aaaaaaaaa bbbbb cccccccccc ... total (10/32) ... dddddddddd ToTal(1/10) eeeeeeeeeeee.'

# regex pattern
ptn = r'(?i)total\s*\(\d+/\d+\)'

# check how the pattern works
re.findall(ptn, x)
#['total (10/32)', 'ToTal(1/10)']
```

**Where:** `(?mode)` is used to turn the listed modes(iLmsux) on for the entire regex. for example, you can add `(?ism)some_pattern` to turn on `ignore-case`, `dotall` and `multiline` modes for `some_pattern`.

Comment: I would like to find the contents of an entire column that contains only the contents of the column in the Excel column, such as 'total (10/32)' with the regular expression applied. But, only one of the contents is displayed.
p = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
text= repr(p.(csv category name)) 
items = re.findall'(?i)total\s*\(\d+/\d+\)', text)
items

only 'total (10/26)'

Comment: @tomy, if you are using Pandas, then `df.loc[df.category.str.contains(ptn),'category']`  to get all text in df.category which contains texts like `total (10/26)`, where `ptn` is what was defined in my post.